# How to synchronize 2 ConcurrentHashMaps?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to write a match maker for buying and selling items. Internally, I am using 2 `HashMaps`, 1 for buys and one for sells for each item i.e. if a user sends me a buy request I put it in my buy `HashMap` and vice versa. The key is the price while the value is a queue of orders at that price (so that I can entertain requests on a FIFO basis if they have the same price. Once I receive a request e.g. buy, I look in to the sell `HashMap` for any matches. Users can change the quantity or price of what they want to buy but they not the item itself e.g. can change a bike buying request's price or quantity but cannot change bike to boat)

I would like to make this multithreaded so multiple requests can be handled at the same time. So I made my `hashmaps` in to `ConcurrentHashMaps` and the queue in the value a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. However, there still can be concurrency issues e.g. I am looking in to the sell map to find a match for my buy request but while I am making the match that sell request gets amended by the user to, say, a different price.

How can I synchronize the two maps with `eachother`? I would like to lock the same segment (i.e. the queue at that price) in both maps at the same time.

Comment: Maybe use a single map, and just mark each order as either buy or sell?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for you is to use `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. This will help the reader thread to read unless anybody is writing to the Map. You can also achieve the same using a synchronized block to perform all the operations, But that will not scale.

for `ReentrantReadWriteLock` doc Please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html

Comment: But that means that I will be locking both maps when any operation is happening. Doesn't this defeat the purpose of ConcurrentHashMap that allows 16 threads simultaneously? I only want to lock the values at the key I am working with in both maps and allow access to other keys.

Comment: Your question was, you want to perform thread-safe operations across two Map. Also, ReadWrite Lock will only block in case of a write operation.

Answer (score 0):

Add single Map where you keep track of available stock, do your locks only there.

Note: Also ConcurrentHashMap doesn't lock single entry it locks bucket so there may be more elements.